# How can I check if a printer already exists before attempting to add it?

Tags: windows, powershell, printers, login-script, network-printers

I recently started getting into PowerShell with very basic lines/scripts. I need some assistance with a printer script that I have that runs under a user's login at logon.

Currently, every time the users log in the printer script will run (even if the printers are added, it will re-add them). This takes a while each time and I feel I could be smarter about how this is done.

I'd like to reconfigure the script to only run if the printers do not exist.

Below is my code:

```powershell
add-printer -connectionname "\\PRINT01.mydomain.local\L1-Printer1"
add-printer -connectionname "\\PRINT01.mydomain.local\L1-Printer2"
add-printer -connectionname "\\PRINT01.mydomain.local\L1-Printer3"

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" -Name "LegacyDefaultPrinterMode" -Value 1 –Force
$wsnObj = New-Object -COM WScript.Network
$wsnObj.SetDefaultPrinter("\\PRINT01.mydomain.local\L1-Printer1")
```

Real names have been redacted for privacy purposes!

**EDIT**

Get-Printer output below:

```
Name                           ComputerName    Type         DriverName                PortName        Shared   Published  DeviceType     
----                           ------------    ----         ----------                --------        ------   ---------  ----------     
Microsoft XPS Document Writer                  Local        Microsoft XPS Document... PORTPROMPT:     False    False      Print          
L1-Printer1                                Local        HP Laserjet 700 PCL6      PORTPROMPT:     True     False      Print
```

Comment: Take a look at `Get-Printer` with the help of an `if(){}` statement. Seems pretty straight forward. Query the printers first, then check if the printer is already mapped, else map it.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me an example of how this would look? I understood I needed an if statement but wasn't sure how to present it into code...

Comment: please post the text you get from that `Get-Printer` call - add it to your Question &  wrap it in code formatting markers so everyone can find it and easily read it.

Comment: Thanks Lee, amended original post with the Get-Printer output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, here's an approach you can take:

```
$printersList = @('L1-Printer1','L1-Printer2','L1-Printer3')
$printersList | ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $printersMapped = Get-Printer
    } -Process {
        if ($_ -in $printersMapped.Name) {
            Write-Verbose -Message "$_ already mapped!"
            #continue
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose -Message "Mapping printer $_"
            Add-Printer -ConnectionName ("\\PRINT01.mydomain.local\" + $_)
        }
    } -End {
        # if printer is default do nothing.
        # else: set default.
    }
```

We can create an array of the printer's that are supposed to be there. Loop through each one, while making a single call to `Get-Printer` to check if it's there or not. Then map the printer if it's not.

There is some *sudo-code* in the `-End` clause that you can implement to set the printer as default if not already set.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you. 

This has helped me understand arrays more and how they can be utilised. I've even used the "ShareName" instead of "Name" to make it easier to manage.